# How to rectify acceleration vibration signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I have acceleration vibration signal containing 2500 data points. What I need to do is rectifying the signal becomes no negative values but still has same mean and standard deviation as the original signal as seen [here](http://sci-hub.se/10.1115/1.2831123) in Fig 4. This need basically for calculating the rectified skewness of the signal.

my questions:

1. How to rectify the vibration signal as my description?
2. What is the formula for calculating rectified skewness?

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to do is rectifying the signal becomes no negative values but still has same mean and standard deviation as the original signal as seen here in Fig 4

You can't. If you rectify it the mean MUST change (unless the signal is all positive to start with). The paper does just a simple rectification and does NOT preserve mean or standard deviation.

Comment: so how to do the rectification so the original data and the rectified one has the same amount of area under curve?

Comment: What "curve" and what "area"? All PDFs have the same "area under the curve"  which is 1. That's the whole point of a PDF. Do you mean the area under the signal itself? That would simply be the mean, which you cannot preserve by rectifying.